# Variation of metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, variational-calculus

In Weinberg's Gravtation and Cosmology Part four chapter 12 section 2. There is a equation I don't quiet understand which is shown below.

$$0=\delta (g_{\mu \nu}g^{\nu \lambda})=g_{\mu \nu}\delta (g^{\nu \lambda})+g^{\nu \lambda}\delta (g_{\mu \nu})$$

I think $g_{\mu \nu}g^{\nu \lambda}$ is not constant, why the darivation of it is zero?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$g_{\mu\lambda}g^{\lambda\nu}=\delta_\mu^\nu$ **is** constant, so its variation is zero.

You can also write this equation as $g g^{-1} = 1$, where $1$ is the identity tensor. The variation of $g^{-1}$ is **defined** such that $gg^{-1}=1$ remains true after the variation.

Comment: Identity **tensor**, btw +1

Comment: @basics An up-down 2-index tensor is a matrix :)

Comment: @Andrew An up-down 2-index tensor is a linear transformation from a vector space to itself. It becomes a matrix the moment you settle on a coordinate grid and use said coordinate grid to describe the tensor as a two-dimensional array of numbers.

Comment: @Andrew I have to disagree, firmly, since this is one of the easiest thing to believe to mess everything up with tensors. I'd agree if you say "the components of a $2^{nd}$-order tensor can be collected in a matrix"